# Win10 broke printf function

Tags: c, windows-10, printf

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    float f = 1717.7890625;
    printf( "%.6f", f );
    return 0;
}
```

I compiled this code with Visual Studio 19 (16.9.2) for x64 arch and ran the result on two my Windows 10 PCs:

1. Version 1909 (OS build 18363.1440) -> Debug and Release: `1717.789063`
2. Version 2004 (OS build 19041.867) -> Debug: `1717.789063` Release: `1717.789062`

What is the cause of the difference between the Debug and Release results on new version? How can I fix it to make results identical on both versions?

**Addition:**
The code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    double f = 0.25;
    printf( "%.1f", f );
    return 0;
}
```

has the same behavior on new vs old Win10 versions. I suggest, that's an error in newer ucrtbase.dll version

Comment: Is using `1717.7890625f` any different?, you are assigning a double to a float right now (IIRC).

Comment: I don't think either behavior (rounding-up or rounding down) merits the term "broke"; either behavior is valid.

Comment: Possibly the release build optimizes out `f` and uses the double value directly. The debug build will store the double value into a float (truncating it) then converts it back to a double to pass to `printf`. What results do you get if you use `cout` instead of `printf`?

Comment: `std::numeric_limits<float>::digits10;` tells you how many digits of a float are significant in a base 10 representation

Comment: In fact if you go to https://h-schmidt.net/FloatConverter/ you'll discover that 1717.7890625 is exactly representable in an IEEE 32-bit float. Probably is possibly due to some library change - what's installed on 1909 vs 2004, and some unfortunate difference in debug vs. release, possibly related to floating point flags (that you normally never touch).

Comment: Compilers (and their libraries) _do_ have errors related to fp rounding for I/O.  See for example [this blog post "inconsistent rounding of printed floating point numbers" from 10 years ago](https://www.exploringbinary.com/inconsistent-rounding-of-printed-floating-point-numbers/).  It's a little surprising that there's a difference between debug and release libraries delivered on the same OS, but probably _not_ unprecedented.

Comment: The numbers `1717.789063f` and `1717.789062f` are identical when it comes to `float`s, `1717.789063f == 1717.789062f` will evaluate to true.

Comment: Floating point conversion is exceptionally hard and many standard libraries still have bugs / implementation defined behaviour (it's hard to tell the difference if they don't make the documentation easy to find) see here for a blog that explores issues with floating point (not mine) https://www.exploringbinary.com/tag/floating-point/

Comment: @RichardCritten - oh yes, "Exploring binary" is the definite goto for learning about this.

Comment: You are stretching the `float` beyond its number of significant digits. Even `1717.78901f == 1717.789063f`. If you are relying on the last digits, then it is an error to use `float` in this case. I think @1201ProgramAlarm is probably right that the difference is due to the `float` being optimized away in the release build.

Comment: By design, read the [[!IMPORTANT] note](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/cpp-docs/blob/master/docs/c-runtime-library/reference/printf-printf-l-wprintf-wprintf-l.md).  Why the debug build doesn't match the release build is however not so obvious to me.  Best to click the [Issue button](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/cpp-docs/issues).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I found the cause of such different behavior of program between windows versions and debug/release modes.

The new windows update (19041.* if I understand correctly) changed rounding rules for fractional part of floating point types: previously it was rounding to greater in case of end with 5: `1.25 -> 1.3`, but now it's rounding to nearest even: `1.25 -> 1.2`, `1.35 -> 1.4`.

To understand the difference between debug and release on new Win 10 version it's needed to notice about the **ucrtbase.dll** usage and update rules.

1. Debug and release versions of every application use **ucrtbase.dll** or **ucrtbased.dll** **from C:\Windows\System32 or C:\Windows\SysWOW64**
2. It's release version (**ucrtbase.dll**) *is a part of Windows 10* and can be updated only with Windows update. But it's debug version (**ucrtbased.dll**) is not updated with Win 10 update, but can be updated with installation of newer Windows 10 SDK (for example, in Visual Studio Installer).

So, the solution is to install new Windows 10 SDK on new Windows 10 version to achieve the same behavior or switch printf() function to fmt::printf() function from https://github.com/fmtlib/fmt, for example, to make result to be the same on all windows versions.

Comment: looks like [this bug](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/incorrect-result-when-printing-6917529027641081856/1093399) in 19041 so you can just add  legacy_stdio_float_rounding.obj option to the linker. Also this https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/different-printf-double-rounding-behaviour-between/1085732